# How to declare ngif value by concatenate in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Trying to hide bullet point by ngIf but not working. How to declare an ngif value by concatenating If anyone knows, please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let season of seasons; index as i">
        <span *ngIf="season.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('') + i" class="bullet"></span>
        <p (click)="hides(season)" matLine>{{ season }}</p>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-uewc3u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: `"season.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('') + i"` will be pretty much always truthy. What is the expected behavior, what's supposed to be hidden?

Comment: @mbojko: Trying to hide bullet point by clicking the text. Please check my stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your solution is overcomplicated. Just store the index of clicked position

```
<p matLine (click)="hides(i)">{{ season }}</p>
```

```
  hiddenIndex = -1;

  hides(val: number) {
    this.hiddenIndex = val;
  }
```

and hide the element:

```
    <span class="bullet" *ngIf="hiddenIndex !== i"></span>
```

The groupid0 and the rest of the variables should go. Here's a modified stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-fkttxa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify your data seasons and become like this

for app.component.html

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let season of seasons; index as i">
    <span class="bullet" *ngIf="season.bullet"></span>
    <p matLine (click)="hides(season)">{{ season.title }}</p>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

for app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface Season {
  title: string;
  bullet: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  seasons: any[] = [
    { title: 'Group id', bullet: true },
    { title: 'Group name', bullet: true },
    { title: 'Group value', bullet: true },
  ];

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  hides(val: any) {
    const index = this.seasons.findIndex((item) => item.title === val.title);
    val.bullet
      ? (this.seasons[index]['bullet'] = false)
      : (this.seasons[index]['bullet'] = true);
  }
}
```

More detail https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-pa4aus?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: as you pass the entire object season, you can use simply `val.buttent=!val.bullet` inside your function. Even you can use in .html directly `(click)="season.bullet=!season.bullet"` without any function.